# How to prevent elements being added to a Javascript array from being overridden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I currently have `addToClients()` that adds a new element to the `clients` array when the button is being pressed. I want to add the new value to `clients` whenever the button is pressed, and have the value maintain in the array even after we input a new element(so I can use the `autocomplete` feature of jQuery). 
However, now whenever I press submit again, the previous element being added is being overridden by the new element, so I can't keep it in the array (FYI `clients` array is in a separate js file from this html file that contains these code). Is there any problem in my implementation? 
Here is what the html page looks like:[image]

```
function addToClients(){
            if (!($("#client-name").val() in clients)){
                clients.push($("#client-name").val())
            }
        }
```

The HTML code related to this part is here:

```
<input type = "text"
                 id = "client-name"
                 onkeypress="auto()" 
                 placeholder="Client">
         <input type = "text" id = "reams" placeholder="#reams">
         <button id="btn"> Submit</button>
```

Here is the array in a separate js file linked to the HTML

```
 clients = [
          "Shake Shack",
          "Toast",
          "Starbucks",
    ];
```

Comment: you have two inputs with the same ID. try changing that first

Comment: Thanks for spotting it! I changed it but nothing happened.

Comment: how are you accessing the array in the separate file? i don't think you are overwriting the previous element with the new element, i think you are calling the original array and just adding the new element to that

Comment: Hi,I linked the js file in <head> and just directly accessed the array. If that is the case, how can I maintain the modified version of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will do:

```
if (jQuery.inArray( $("#client-name").val(), clients ) == -1){
     clients.push($("#client-name").val())
 }
```

Comment: I tried it but i don't think it is different from what I had.

Comment: @timeRocket Sorry, I've changed it. Check again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` which will check value have exist in array then return true or false ...

```js
var arr = [1,4,7];
var added = 4;

if(!arr.includes(added)) {
  arr.push(added);
}
console.log(arr);
```